# How to display the tree in a different order?

Tags: php, tree

In this case, the tree is displayed in this form

```
level 3
  level 3.1
    level 3.1.1
    level 3.1.2
      level 3.1.2.1
level 2
  level 2.1
  level 2.2
  level 2.3
level 1
  level 1.1
  level 1.2
  level 1.3
  level 1.4
    level 1.4.1
```

How can it be flipped so that it displays correctly?
I tried everything and nothing works

Here is the fully working code:

the **rebuildTree** function creates the correct structure, and the **printTree** function displays the result

```
<?php
$tree = [
   ['name' => 'level 1',     'id' => 1,  'pid' => 0],
    ['name' => 'level 1.1',   'id' => 2,  'pid' => 1],
    ['name' => 'level 1.2',   'id' => 3,  'pid' => 1],
    ['name' => 'level 1.3',   'id' => 4,  'pid' => 1],
    ['name' => 'level 2',     'id' => 5,  'pid' => 0],
    ['name' => 'level 2.1',   'id' => 6,  'pid' => 5],
    ['name' => 'level 2.2',   'id' => 7,  'pid' => 5],
    ['name' => 'level 3',     'id' => 8,  'pid' => 0],
    ['name' => 'level 3.1',   'id' => 9,  'pid' => 8],
    ['name' => 'level 3.1.1', 'id' => 10, 'pid' => 9],
    ['name' => 'level 3.1.2', 'id' => 11, 'pid' => 9],
    ['name' => 'level 1.4', 'id' => 12, 'pid' => 1],
    ['name' => 'level 2.3',   'id' => 13,  'pid' => 5],
    ['name' => 'level 3.1.2.1', 'id' => 14, 'pid' => 11],
    ['name' => 'level 1.4.1', 'id' => 15, 'pid' => 12],
];

function rebuildTree($tree){
    foreach ($tree as $key => $node) {
        $branches[$node['id']] = $node;
    }
    $rootNodes = [];
    foreach ($tree as $node) {
        if ($node['pid'] === 0) {
            $rootNodes[] = &$branches[$node['id']];
        } else {
            $branches[$node['pid']]['chld'][] = &$branches[$node['id']];
        }
    }
    return $rootNodes;
}

function printTree($tree) {
    $stack = [];
    foreach ($tree as $node) {
        if (empty($node['pid'])) {
            $stack[] = [$node, 0];
        }
    }
    
    while (!empty($stack)) {
    
        list($node, $depth) = array_pop($stack);
        
        echo str_repeat('  ', $depth) . $node['name'] . PHP_EOL;

        if (isset($node['chld'])) {
            foreach (array_reverse($node['chld']) as $child) {
                $stack[] = [$child, $depth + 1];
            }
        }
    }
}

$arr = rebuildTree($tree);
printTree($arr);
```

And I don't want to use recursion, they say it's very bad.

Comment: _"And I don't want to use recursion, they say it's very bad"_ - If someone says that recursion is "very bad" as a blanket statement, then they are just wrong. When iterating through and working with tree data, just like you are, then there's nothing wrong with it. It can even be the only sane choice. It's when you use it instead of other sensible options you should rethink it's usage.

Comment: *"How can it be flipped...?"*: what does that mean? Can you provide the *expected* output?

Comment: What would start from level 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be proven they are equivalent, recursive and iterative solutions. So I'll present to you a recursive one, first.

```php
function printTreeRecursive($tree, $depth = 0)
{
    foreach ($tree as $node) {
        echo str_repeat('  ', $depth) . $node['name'] . PHP_EOL;
        if (isset($node['chld'])) {
            printTreeRecursive($node['chld'], $depth + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
level 1
  level 1.1
  level 1.2
  level 1.3
  level 1.4
    level 1.4.1
level 2
  level 2.1
  level 2.2
  level 2.3
level 3
  level 3.1
    level 3.1.1
    level 3.1.2
      level 3.1.2.1
```

As for non recursive, your method is perfect, except you would want to reverse the stack in the first place.

```php
function printTree($tree)
{
    $stack = [];
    foreach ($tree as $node) {
        if (empty($node['pid'])) {
            $stack[] = [$node, 0];
        }
    }

    // add this line: 
    $stack = array_reverse($stack);

    while (!empty($stack)) {

        list($node, $depth) = array_pop($stack);

        echo str_repeat('  ', $depth) . $node['name'] . PHP_EOL;

        if (isset($node['chld'])) {
            foreach (array_reverse($node['chld']) as $child) {
                $stack[] = [$child, $depth + 1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution without recursion, with stack and with a single loop. In the stack are saved the address of the active branch and the last processed position instead of the complete sub-branch(es).

```
function printTree($tree)
{
    $stack = [];
    $subTree = &$tree;  // the considered branch
    $ind = 0;

    // we test if we have more elements in the current branch or if we have an upper branch to process
    while (($into = ($ind < count($subTree)))  ||  count($stack))
    {
        if (!$into)  // if all elements of current branch are processed, we restore the upper branch
        {
            [$subTree, $ind] = array_pop($stack);
        }
        else
        {
            // let's print the string, the indentation is calculated by the stack level
            echo str_repeat(' ', (count($stack) + 1) * 2), $subTree[$ind]['name'],  PHP_EOL;

            // if there's a child branch we save the current processing branch and position
            // and we prepare to process the sub-branch
            if ($subTree[$ind]['chld'] ?? false)
            {
                $stack[] = [&$subTree, $ind];
                $subTree = &$subTree[$ind]['chld'];
                $ind = -1;  // will become 0 in the next instruction ~ if you don't like it use: $ind = 0; continue;
            }
        }

        $ind++;
    }
}
```